# Unterschied zwischen "dienen + Dat." und "dienen zu"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl bedeutet dienen mit Dativ, dass man z. B. einer Person gegenüber **unterwürfig** ist (eine unter vielen ähnlichen Bedeutungen).

Dienen + zu hingegen benutze ich hingegen, um eine **Funktion** auszudrücken, z. B. „Das Zeug dient zum Spielen”.

Ich habe aber einen Text gefunden, wo der Autor ständig die **erste** Möglichkeit verwendet, um die Bestimmung einer Sache zu erklären.

Beispiel: *Diese Tabellen dienen überwiegend dem Buchen.*

Ist der vorstehende Satz korrekt?

Answer (score 2):

"Diese Tabellen dienen überwiegend dem Buchen."

Ist vollkommen korrekt. Die Tabellen "dienen" dem Zwecke des Buchens.

Viel mehr gibt es da auch nicht zu erläutern oder sagen, ich sehe in den Satzstellungen keine Probleme oder Konflikte.

Answer (score 1):

"Dem Zweck des Buchens dienen" ist genauso korrekt wie "zu dem Zweck des Buchens dienen". Wenn man das Wort Zweck hinzufügt, ist die Phrase auch gebräulicher als lediglich 'dem Buchen dienen'.

Answer (score 0):

Völlig korrekt. Ich kann deine Beobachtung im übrigen auch nicht ganz teilen. Sie stimmt, wenn es sich um Personen handelt, die anderen Personen dienen.

> James dienst seit schon Jahren dem Lord of Gloucestershire.

Aber dieselbe Konstruktion ist auch gebräuchlich, um den Verwendungszweck von Gegenständen zu beschreiben:

> Die Schaumrollenform dient der Zubereitung von Schaumrollen.
>   Unser neuer Prüfstand dient der Messung der Abgaswerte.
>   Diese Tabelle dient der Personalplanung.